# Additional class to woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params

Tags: woocommerce

How can I add additional class (img-fluid) to filter `woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params`?
I do not wanna edit the `woocommerce\includes\wc-template-function.php` which is a core file.

I edited the core file and it works fine, but I know that it is not the right way of doing this.

```
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
            array(
                'title'                   => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
                'data-src'                => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                'data-large_image'        => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
                'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr( $full_src[1] ),
                'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr( $full_src[2] ),
                'class'                   => esc_attr( $main_image ? 'wp-post-image img-fluid' : '' ),
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $image_size,
            $main_image
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Never edit core plugin files because whenever you update the plugin all of your customization will be override.

You can use [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) to modify or add data.

try adding this in your theme's functions.php.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params', 'ze_add_classes_to_images_custom', 10, 4);
function ze_add_classes_to_images_custom($attachment_data ,$attachment_id, $image_size , $main_image){
    $attachment_data['class'] .= ' img-fluid';
    return $attachment_data;
}
```